# Tumblr integration in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, tumblr

Using https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK link, i am trying to integrate tumbler sdk and compile the Photosharing sample project under the Example folder. But i am getting the following error message:

```
diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
```

I am not able to understand the pod file concept. Can anyone please explain me the proper steps that need to be followed to integrate this sdk in iOS app.

Comment: You do not need to use PODs for this, you can just download the framework and integrate it into you project.

Comment: i have just downlload the framework and run the example project. but i am getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: I just downloaded the example as well and the project is just broken. YOu will need to check all the paths and fix it.

Comment: Steps that i have followed:  

Step1: Downloaded the zip file https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK. 

Step2: Unzip the folder, go to Example folder. Then PhotoPostExample.
Step3: Run the PhotoPostExample.xcodeproj
Step4: Getting these error messages:
diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sanbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install'.

Answer (score 0):

The targets in your xcode projects have a build phase to perform a lock file. But it seems like your xcode projects configurations are not referencing the user defined settings configured in `Pods/Pods-libPods.xcconfig`.

It looks like you are trying to link a Pod with specific targets in multiple xcodeprojs. If my assumption is correct, you are using the target attribute incorrectly. The target attribute creates a new static library within the Pods project that includes the Pods you configured within that target.

The default target for the Pods `xcodeproj` is `libPods` which generates the `libPods.a` static library. This is generated if you do not specify a target. So if you don't care about generating multiple static libaries in the Pods `xcodeproj`, don't bother defining a target and use the `link_with` attribute to link the default libPods target (static library) to the targets in your xcodeprojs.
check this link for further reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795280/using-cocoapods-with-multiple-projects)

Comment: Can you please explain the steps where these settings should be done in targets?